# Python Side-by-side box plots on same figure

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a box plot in Python 2.7 for each categorical value in column E from the Pandas dataframe below

```
          A         B         C         D  E
0  0.647366  0.317832  0.875353  0.993592  1
1  0.504790  0.041806  0.113889  0.445370  2
2  0.769335  0.120647  0.749565  0.935732  3
3  0.215003  0.497402  0.795033  0.246890  1
4  0.841577  0.211128  0.248779  0.250432  1
5  0.045797  0.710889  0.257784  0.207661  4
6  0.229536  0.094308  0.464018  0.402725  3
7  0.067887  0.591637  0.949509  0.858394  2
8  0.827660  0.348025  0.507488  0.343006  3
9  0.559795  0.820231  0.461300  0.921024  1
```

I would be willing to do this with Matplotlib or any other plotting library. So far the above code can plot all the categories combined on one plot. Here is the code to generate the above data and produce the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
df['E'] = [1,2,3,1,1,4,3,2,3,1]

# Boxplot
bp = ax.boxplot(df.iloc[:,:-1].values, widths=0.2)
plt.show()
```

In this example, the categories are 1,2,3,4. I would like to plot separate boxplots side-by-side on the same figure, for only categories 1 and 2 and show the category names in the legend.

Is there a way to do this?

**Additional Information:**

The output should look similar to the 3rd figure from [here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) - replace "Yes","No" by "1","2".

Comment: This example doesn't work because matplotlib plots the data by the columns, so there will be 4 boxplots, labeled A, B, C, and D.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I would like to have 4 box plots for category 1 and 4 box plots for category 2. I added a link to the OP showing something similar being done elsewhere. I am looking for a similar plot to that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Starting with this:

```
import numpy
import pandas
from matplotlib import pyplot
import seaborn
seaborn.set(style="ticks")

# Data
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.rand(10,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['E'] = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1]
```

You've got a couple of options. If separate axes are ok,

```
fig, axes = pyplot.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(12, 5), sharey=True)
df.query("E in [1, 2]").boxplot(by='E', return_type='axes', ax=axes)
```

[image]

If you want 1 axes, I think seaborn will be easier. You just need to clean up your data.

```
ax = (
    df.set_index('E', append=True)  # set E as part of the index
      .stack()                      # pull A - D into rows 
      .to_frame()                   # convert to a dataframe
      .reset_index()                # make the index into reg. columns
      .rename(columns={'level_2': 'quantity', 0: 'value'})  # rename columns
      .drop('level_0', axis='columns')   # drop junk columns
      .pipe((seaborn.boxplot, 'data'), x='E', y='value', hue='quantity', order=[1, 2])  
)
seaborn.despine(trim=True)
```

[image]

The cool thing about seaborn is that tweaking the parameters slightly can achieve a lot in terms of the plot's layout. If we switch our `hue` and `x` variables, we get:

```
ax = (
    df.set_index('E', append=True)  # set E as part of the index
      .stack()                      # pull A - D into rows 
      .to_frame()                   # convert to a dataframe
      .reset_index()                # make the index into reg. columns
      .rename(columns={'level_2': 'quantity', 0: 'value'})  # rename columns
      .drop('level_0', axis='columns')   # drop junk columns
      .pipe((seaborn.boxplot, 'data'), x='quantity', y='value', hue='E', hue_order=[1, 2])  
)
seaborn.despine(trim=True)
```

[image]

If you're curious, the resulting dataframe looks something like this:

```
    E quantity     value
0   1        A  0.935433
1   1        B  0.862290
2   1        C  0.197243
3   1        D  0.977969
4   2        A  0.675037
5   2        B  0.494440
6   2        C  0.492762
7   2        D  0.531296
8   3        A  0.119273
9   3        B  0.303639
10  3        C  0.911700
11  3        D  0.807861
```

Comment: When I try `df = df.set_index('E', append=True).stack().to_frame().rename(columns={'level_2': 'quantity', 0: 'value'}).drop('level_0', axis='columns')` I get an error `ValueError: labels ['level_0'] not contained in axis`. I would prefer to be able to see the dataframe before going to plot it. Is it possible to generate the Pandas DF first before generating the boxplot? Also is it possible to customize things such as whisker size, cap size, flier size/color in seaborn?

Comment: Yes. Just don't pipe it into seaborn.boxplot and make the call to that separately.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is it possible to customize things such as whisker size, cap size, flier size/color in seaborn? Eg. in matplotlib, I would have done `bp = ax.boxplot()` and then for whisker in bp['whiskers']: whisker.set(lw=0.5,linestyle='-'). When I try this in with `bp = sns.boxplot()` I get `TypeError: 'Axes' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. Can these customizations be made?

Comment: `seaborn.boxplots` passes all additional kwargs directly to `pyplot.boxplot`, whose documentation is here: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot. If you want to get into the weeds about customizing boxplots, that merits a separate question

Comment: Great answer. This answers my question and gives an alternate way to quickly visualize the dataframe.

Comment: Regarding The customization of one aspect of boxplots, I did post a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199780/seaborn-boxplot-box-assign-custom-edge-colors-from-python-list. If you could take a look there that would be great. For this question, it won't be necessary. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

An addition to @Paul_H answer.

Side-by-side boxplots on the single `matplotlib.axes.Axes`, no seaborn:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['E'] = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]

mask_e = df['E'] == 1

# prepare data
data_to_plot = [df[mask_e]['A'], df[~mask_e]['A'],
                df[mask_e]['B'], df[~mask_e]['B'],
                df[mask_e]['C'], df[~mask_e]['C'],
                df[mask_e]['D'], df[~mask_e]['D']]

# Positions defaults to range(1, N+1) where N is the number of boxplot to be drawn.
# we will move them a little, to visually group them
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
box = plt.boxplot(data_to_plot,
                  positions=[1, 1.6, 2.5, 3.1, 4, 4.6, 5.5, 6.1],
                  labels=['A1','A0','B1','B0','C1','C0','D1','D0'])
```

[image: result]