# Side-by-side boxplots with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I need to plot comparison of five variable, stored in pandas `dataframe`. I used an example [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191983/python-side-by-side-box-plots-on-same-figure), it worked, but now I need to change the axes and titles, but I'm struggling to do so.

Here is my data:

```
df1.groupby('cls').head()
Out[171]: 
   sensitivity  specificity  accuracy       ppv       auc       cls
0     0.772091     0.824487  0.802966  0.799290  0.863700       sig
1     0.748931     0.817238  0.776366  0.785910  0.859041       sig
2     0.774016     0.805909  0.801975  0.789840  0.853132       sig
3     0.826670     0.730071  0.795715  0.784150  0.850024       sig
4     0.781112     0.803839  0.824709  0.791530  0.863411       sig
0     0.619048     0.748290  0.694969  0.686138  0.713899  baseline
1     0.642348     0.702076  0.646216  0.674683  0.712632  baseline
2     0.567344     0.765410  0.710650  0.665614  0.682502  baseline
3     0.644046     0.733645  0.754621  0.683485  0.734299  baseline
4     0.710077     0.653871  0.707933  0.684313  0.732997  baseline
```

Here is my code:

```
>> fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=5, figsize=(12, 5), sharey=True)
>> df1.query("cls in ['sig', 'baseline']").boxplot(by='cls', return_type='axes', ax=axes)
```

And the resulting pictures are:

[image: pictures of results]

**How to:**

- change the title ('Boxplot groupped by cls')
- get rid of annoying [cls] plotted along the horizontal line
- reorder the plotted categories as they appear in df1? (first sensitivity, followed by speci...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using `seaborn`

Here is an example that might help you:

Imports

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
```

Make data

```
data = {'sensitivity' : np.random.normal(loc = 0, size = 10),
        'specificity' : np.random.normal(loc = 0, size = 10),
        'accuracy' : np.random.normal(loc = 0, size = 10),
        'ppv' : np.random.normal(loc = 0, size = 10),
        'auc' : np.random.normal(loc = 0, size = 10),
        'cls' : ['sig', 'sig', 'sig', 'sig', 'sig', 'baseline', 'baseline', 'baseline', 'baseline', 'baseline']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Seaborn has a nifty tool called `factorplot` that creates a grid of subplots where the rows/cols are built with your data. To be able to do this, we need to "melt" the `df` into a more usable shape.

```
df_melt = df.melt(id_vars = 'cls',
                  value_vars = ['accuracy',
                                'auc',
                                'ppv',
                                'sensitivity',
                                'specificity'],
                  var_name = 'columns')
```

Now we can create the `factorplot` using the col "columns".

```
a = sns.factorplot(data = df_melt,
                   x = 'cls',
                   y = 'value',
                   kind = 'box', # type of plot
                   col = 'columns',
                   col_order = ['sensitivity', # custom order of boxplots
                                'specificity',
                                'accuracy',
                                'ppv',
                                'auc']).set_titles('{col_name}') # remove 'column = ' part of title

plt.show()
```

[image: factorplot]

You can also just use Seaborn's boxplot.

```
b = sns.boxplot(data = df_melt,
                hue = 'cls', # different colors for different 'cls'
                x = 'columns',
                y = 'value',
                order = ['sensitivity', # custom order of boxplots
                         'specificity',
                         'accuracy',
                         'ppv',
                         'auc'])

sns.plt.title('Boxplot grouped by cls') # You can change the title here
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot]

This will give you the same plot but all in one figure instead of subplots. It also allows you to change the title of the figure with one line. Unfortunately I can't find a way to remove the 'columns' subtitle but hopefully this will get you what you need.

**EDIT**

To view the plots sideways:
Factorplot
Swap your `x` and `y` values, change `col = 'columns'` to `row = 'columns'`, change `col_order = [...]` to `row_order = [...]`, and change `'{col_name}'` to `'{row_name}'` like so

```
a1 = sns.factorplot(data = df_melt,
                    x = 'value',
                    y = 'cls',
                    kind = 'box', # type of plot
                    row = 'columns',
                    row_order = ['sensitivity', # custom order of boxplots
                                 'specificity',
                                 'accuracy',
                                 'ppv',
                                 'auc']).set_titles('{row_name}') # remove 'column = ' part of title

plt.show()
```

[image: h factorplot]
Boxplot
Swap your `x` and `y` values then add the parameter `orient = 'h'` like so

```
b1 = sns.boxplot(data = df_melt,
                 hue = 'cls',
                 x = 'value',
                 y = 'columns',
                 order = ['sensitivity', # custom order of boxplots
                         'specificity',
                         'accuracy',
                         'ppv',
                         'auc'],
                 orient = 'h')

sns.plt.title('Boxplot grouped by cls')
plt.show()
```

[image: h boxplot]

Comment: thanks! Is there a way to display plots vertically and NOT horizontally? Instead of having 1X5 plots, I need to transpose and get 5X1 plot with `factorplot`?

Comment: How do you get the nice gray background?

Comment: @YonatanSimson at the time of writing that was the default. You can change the style to `ggplot` which is similar to it:
`from matplotlib import style`
`style.use('ggplot')`

Comment: @YonatanSimson you can also try `sns.set_style('dark')`

Comment: @IanThompson Thanks. I used sns.set(). Previous versions used to do this as part of the import and now it has to be done manually

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

```
fig, axes = pyplot.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(12, 5), sharey=True)
df.query("E in [1, 2]").boxplot(by='E', return_type='axes', ax=axes, column=list('bcda')) # Keeping original columns order
pyplot.suptitle('Boxplot') # Changing title
[ax.set_xlabel('') for ax in axes] # Changing xticks for all plots
```