# Transpose factorplot in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975337/side-by-side-boxplots-with-pandas) how to draw several box plots, now I am wondering how transpose the factor plot and instead of having 1x5 pictures

[image]

I need to get it as 5x1.

**How to vertically align the factorplot?**

Comment: @Serenity, nope, didn't work. I also tried 'orient = 'v' ', also didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a seaborn boxplot you need to use the `row` argument to supply the quantity to map along the rows, instead of the `col`  argument.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

g = sns.factorplot(y="age", x="embark_town",
                    hue="sex", row="class",
                    data=titanic[titanic.embark_town.notnull()],
                   orient="v", kind="box", size=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]